# If $B$ is a generalised subformula of $\textbf{Q}xA$ then there exists a free term $t$ such that $B$ is a generalised subformula of $[A]_t^x$

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic, proof-theory

Consider formulas $A$ of predicate calculus such that no variables can be bound and free for $A$ at the same time. Term $t$ is said to be free for $x$ in $A$ if $x\notin FV(A)$ or no variables of $t$ appears in $A$ as bound ones. Lets generalise the notion of a subformula: we say that $[A]_t^x$ is a generalised subformula of $\textbf{Q}xA,\:\textbf{Q}\in\{\forall,\exists\},$ if the term $t$ is free for $x$ in A.

Prove that if $B$ is a proper generalised subformula of $\textbf{Q}xA$ where $\textbf{Q}$ is a quantifier then there exists a term $t$ free for $x$ in $A$ such that $B$ is a generalised subformula of $[A]_t^x$.

Intuitively this statement is evident but I am not pretty sure about a formal proof. I've tried to use induction (the base is trivial) but I don't know how exactly must the step look like.

Maybe I overcomplicate and all needed to be said is: if required $t$ does not exist then $B$ is not a generalised subformula for any of $[A]_t^x$ and, hence, it must be the whole $\textbf{Q}xA$ but $B$ is proper. Contradiction.

I am not sure. What can you say?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, can you please tell how must the step of induction look like? I don't really understand that. There are a few cases: 1) $A=(A'\tau A'')$ where $\tau\in\{\&,\vee,\supset\}$; 2) $A=\neg A'$; 3) $A=\textbf{Q'}xA'$. How to deal, for instance, with the first one?

Comment: Consider the example above, with formula $Qx(A_1 \land A_2)$. We have that $[A]^x_t$ will be: $[A_1]^x_t \land [A_2]^x_t$, where $t$ is free for $x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes, this is clear. But where do we use induction? We say: if $B\ne[A]_t^x$ then it must be contained in, for example, $[A_1]_t^x$ or $[A_2]_t^x$. But saying this doesn't we use the statement we need to prove?

Comment: You are right; probably induction is not needed. The issue is: if $B$ is a gen sub of $QxA$, we have already that $t$ is free for $x$ in $A$ and this fact is not affected by the "proper" property. So, in the case above, $B := [A_1]^x_t$ is a subformula in the usual sense of $[A_1 \land A_2]^x_t$ and also in the generalized sense.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think the issue is in the definition of a set $GSF$ of generalised subformulas: in my opinion the most convenient one is recursive: 1. If $A=(A_1\tau A_2)$ then $GSF(A)=\{A\}\cup GSF(A_1)\cup GSF(A_2)$; 2. If $A=\neg A_1$ then $GSF(A)=\{A\}\cup GSF(A_1)$; 3. If $A=\textbf{Q}xA_1$ then $GSF(A)=\{A\}\cup\bigcup\limits_{t\:is\:free\:for\:x}GSF([A]_t^x)$. And I don't actually know which definition do the authors use.

Comment: I.e. a gen sub of $A$ is either the whole $A$ or a gen sub of a 'gen sub of first order for $A$'.

Comment: Your def looks fine; who are "the authors"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, this is an exersize (4 for $\S$6.1) from Ershov, Paliutin. Mathematical Logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, btw, is it possible to describe gen subs the way close to the classical definition of a subformula: a subword which is also a formula?

Comment: Your def is correct; we have to add to the usual recursive clauses for sub-formulas (as substrings of the formula) also the cases regarding the quantifiers: $A[x/t]$ for every "suitable" $t$.

Comment: What is puzzling me is the "proper"... If $B$ is a generalized sub of e.g. $\forall x A$ it is either a "usual" sub or $A[x/t]$ for suitable $t$. In this case, we have that there exists $t$ such that $B$ is sub of $A[x/t]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think 'proper' means only that $B\ne\textbf{Q}xA$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find it in the [English translation](https://ia801005.us.archive.org/25/items/ErshovPalyutinMathematicalLogicMir1984/Ershov-Palyutin-Mathematical_Logic-Mir-1984.pdf)

Comment: For formula $\forall x \Phi$ with atomic $\Phi := R(x)$ we have that $B := [\Phi]^x_t$ is $[R(x)]^x_t = R(t)$ which is a gen-sub of $\forall x \Phi$. Cases with connectives are obvious.

Comment: The only interesting case is with quantifiers, where we can have formulas with nested quantifiers, like e.g. $\forall x \exists y \Phi$ and $B$ is $[\exists y \Phi]^x_t = \exists y [\Phi]^x_t$ where the case $y$ occurring in $t$ is ruled out by the clause that $t$ must be free for $x$.